# React Native Android Swipe Up

Tags: react-native, swipe-gesture

I am making a transportation app and I need a component in React Native that can swipe up when people want to set the location.

How can I make swipe up like in the example image below?

[image: before swipe]

[image: after swipe up]

Anyone has references or a tutorial like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system
Or an easy way using https://github.com/glepur/react-native-swipe-gestures.
I would actually use the module `react-native-swipe-gestures` cause efficient and quick.

Comment: please install the npm package from : https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-sliding-up-panel

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [this library](https://github.com/react-native-vietnam/react-native-swipe-up-down#readme)

**Installation :**

```
npm install react-native-swipe-up-down --save
```

**Basic Usage**

```
import SwipeUpDown from 'react-native-swipe-up-down';


<SwipeUpDown        
    itemMini={<ItemMini />} // Pass props component when collapsed
    itemFull={<ItemFull />} // Pass props component when show full
    onShowMini={() => console.log('mini')}
    onShowFull={() => console.log('full')}
    onMoveDown={() => console.log('down')}
    onMoveUp={() => console.log('up')}
    disablePressToShow={false} // Press item mini to show full
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} // style for swipe
/>
```

**Output :** [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agiletechvn/react-native-swipe-up-down/master/demo.gif)

Comment: I am glad I helped you. Can you please accept and upvote my answer ?